# iterate over all database in prolog

Tags: foreach, prolog

I am new to prolog.I am trying to find topper from the database of student I need help with iteration over all the dataset to find a topper
my code is

```
    student(name(kiran,kumar,b14122),[30,40,60]).
    student(name(nimit,kalal,b14115),[10,30,40]).
    student(name(ramesh,babu,b14222),[40,20,30]).

     %student(name(fname(),lname(),roll_no(),markslist(p(),c(),m())
     sum([],0).
     sum([X|List],Sum) :-
         sum(List,Sum1),plus(Sum1,X,Sum).
     total(Roll_no,T) :- 
         student(name(Fname,Lname,Roll_no),Markslist),sum(Markslist,T).
     topper(Fname,Lname,Totalmarks,Markslist) :-
```

thank you for every help

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: my expected output is student's fname lname total marks and markslist(list of marks)

Comment: You know Prolog has a `sum_list/2` (or `sumlist/2`) predicate that sums up the numbers in a list, right?

Comment: If by "topper" you mean top total score, then the most straightforward approach is to use `setof` and `reverse`. `setof` will collect and sort results, so choose a term form that looks like `Score-Student-ScoreList`, then you can do `topper(Student, MarksList) :- setof(Score-Student-ScoreList, (student(Student, ScoreList), sumlist(ScoreList, Score)), LowToHigh), reverse(LowToHigh, [_-Student-MarksList]).`